# How to use Saveas Method with Iformcollection in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, image-upload, multiple-file-upload

Hello I am trying to upload Multiple Images but i am facing error i cannot use SaveAs with IFormcollection my code is work fine for single image but conflicting in multiple images.
iformcollection does not contain a def for saveas What other method we can use with Iformcollection to upload Multiple Images

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            product.Pro_Pic.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProductPicture/"+product.Pro_Pic.FileName));
            product.Product_Picture = "~/ProductPicture/" +product.Pro_Pic.FileName;

           
            foreach(var file in product.GalleryPic)
            {                    
                product.GalleryPic.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProductPicture/" + product.GalleryPic.FileName););
                product.GalleryPic = "~/ProductPicture/" + product.Pro_Pic.FileName;
            }
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here is my Model Code

```
 [NotMapped]
    public IFormCollection GalleryPic  { get; set; }
```

Comment: In the foreach loop, can you use file.SaveAs() ?

Comment: This is what actually i am asking?

Comment: Then try it and see?

Comment: Same error I tried